# How to add support of windows-1251 encoding for mp3 tags for VLC player

Tags: vlc, music, mp3, encoding, id3

I'm having trouble viewing mp3 tags info using VLC player. The mp3 tags are represented in windows-1251 encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of dealing with the problem is convert the tags to UTF. I've been successfully using [tag2utf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tag2utf/) for that purpose.